# Flutter - I want to update the colors in an animated gradient (animate gradient package) when a carousel slider changes

Tags: flutter, animation

I am trying to make a weather app with a carousel slider and an animated gradient background. To see the forecast, the user swipes between weather cards showing the information for each hour.

I have an animated gradient which acts as a background. This gradient changes between 2 lists of 3 colors automatically. This part is working fine when the page first loads and it loads to the correct color lists for the first weather card (e.g. If the first hour is rainy the background is rainy colors, if the first hour is sunny the background is sunny colors).

However, when the card changes from one type of weather to another, the background doesn't change. I have been trying to figure this out for 4 days and I can't figure out how to do it. I have confirmed through printing that the background colors list is correct.

I will post the code from my main weather page below. If you need any more information or any of the other components, please let me know.

```
import 'package:environment/services/weather.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:animate_gradient/animate_gradient.dart';
import 'package:environment/components/weather_card.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';

class MainWeatherScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainWeatherScreen(
      {super.key,
      this.locationWeather,
      this.locationCity,
      this.locationPollution});

  final dynamic locationWeather;
  final dynamic locationCity;
  final dynamic locationPollution;

  @override
  State<MainWeatherScreen> createState() => _MainWeatherScreenState();
}

class _MainWeatherScreenState extends State<MainWeatherScreen> {
  WeatherModel weather = WeatherModel();
  List<Widget>? weatherCards;
  List backgroundColors = [];
  int carouselIndex = 0;
  List<Color> primaryColors = [];
  List<Color> secondaryColors = [];

  void changeBackgroundColors(int index) {
    setState(() {
      primaryColors = backgroundColors[index]['primary'];
      secondaryColors = backgroundColors[index]['secondary'];
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateUI(
      widget.locationWeather,
      widget.locationCity,
      widget.locationPollution,
    );
  }

  void updateUI(
    dynamic weatherData,
    dynamic cityData,
    dynamic pollutionData,
  ) {
    setState(() {
      if (weatherData == null) {
        weatherCards = [
          const WeatherCard(
            cityName: 'No Data',
            weatherIcon: Icons.broken_image,
            temperature: 0,
            time: '0.00',
            windSpeed: 0.0,
            windDegrees: 0,
            aqi: 0,
            aqiComment: '',
            uvi: 0,
            uviComment: '',
            condition: 0,
            sunrise: '',
            sunset: '',
          )
        ];

        return;
      }

      weatherCards = weatherCardList(weatherData, cityData, pollutionData);
      backgroundColors = weather.getBackgroundColors(weatherData);
      primaryColors = backgroundColors[0]['primary'];
      secondaryColors = backgroundColors[0]['secondary'];
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnimateGradient(
        primaryColors: primaryColors,
        secondaryColors: secondaryColors,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        var weatherData = await weather.getLocationWeather();
                        var cityData = await weather.getCityName();
                        var pollutionData =
                            await weather.getLocationPollution();

                        updateUI(weatherData, cityData, pollutionData);
                      },
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.near_me,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 50.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                CarouselSlider(
                  items: weatherCards,
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    viewportFraction: 1.0,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    height: 600,
                    enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                    onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                      setState(() {
                        carouselIndex = index;
                        changeBackgroundColors(index);
                      });

                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried creating a function to update the primary and secondary colors which is called when the onPageChanged is triggered on the carousel slider. I expected this to update the parameters on the AnimateGradient but the colors stay the same on the app.

I have also tried adding the variables inside the build method but it's still the same result. I feel like I need to call a function to update the animated gradient inside the build method but I don't know how I would do that.

I will learn about debugging on android studio but I'm ready to give this up and realise that the real application was the friends I made along the way!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't think this is the case as the animated background doesn't move anywhere. What I want it to do is rebuild with the new parameters from the background color variables.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, it appears that the changeBackgroundColors() function is appropriately updating the primaryColors and secondaryColors lists. The problem, however, might be that the AnimateGradient widget is not receiving the changed colors.

To remedy this, you must include the revised primaryColors and secondaryColors lists in your build() method and provide them to the AnimateGradient widget. You may achieve this by storing the AnimateGradient widget in a variable and changing its attributes as the colors change.

Here is a newer iteration of your build() method that ought to function:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    var weatherData = await weather.getLocationWeather();
                    var cityData = await weather.getCityName();
                    var pollutionData =
                        await weather.getLocationPollution();

                    updateUI(weatherData, cityData, pollutionData);
                  },
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.near_me,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 50.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            AnimateGradient(
              primaryColors: primaryColors,
              secondaryColors: secondaryColors,
              child: CarouselSlider(
                items: weatherCards,
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  viewportFraction: 1.0,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  height: 600,
                  enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                  onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                    setState(() {
                      carouselIndex = index;
                      changeBackgroundColors(index);
                    });
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Note that I moved the AnimateGradient widget outside of the SafeArea widget and wrapped the CarouselSlider widget with it. This allows us to update the properties of AnimateGradient when the colors change.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I tried the new build method you provided and I still had the same result (the colors remained the same when the carousel slide was changed to one with a different background color).
How could I get the variables inside the build method?